# Read user's environment variable in php script

Tags: php, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, environment-variables

I'm trying to query environment variables that i have set my .bashrc file (i'm running Ubuntu 14.04) in a PHP scripts that run's under Apache server.

When i query the getenv('MY_VAR_NAME') or $_ENV['MY_VAR_NAME'] while accessing the page, it seems that those variables are missing..

My guess is: when the script is been executed the user is www-data, so 'MY_VAR_NAME' is not accessible.

Is there any procedures / best practices to this kind of problems ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without going into why you need to access a specific variable, you can set them in your Apache configuration, by adding:

```
SetEnv VARIABLE_NAME variable_value
```

To your VirtualHost block or .htaccess file.

Alternatively, if you could explain what your script does and why it needs the environment variable, we could suggest a different way of doing.

Comment: That's i know, i have been trying to avoid it form my own reasons, is there any way to do it aside of that ? and is that unsafe to expose the user ubuntu env variable to www-data ?

Comment: Again, it depends on your application's needs. I don't see an inherent risk in passing specific variables to Apache.

Comment: Great thanks, seems like adding the environment variables to the "/etc/apache2/envvars" did the trick